# Find the maximal switching period that ensures asymptotic stability of the switching system.

Tags: matlab, control-theory

I have a time-dependent switched system $\mathbf{\dot{x}} = \mathbf{A}_i\mathbf{x}$. With

$$\mathbf{A}_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  -0.5 & 1 \\
  100 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\mathbf{A}_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -100 \\
-0.5 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now I have to find the maximal switching period which ensures asymptotic stability i.e. the eigenvalues are inside the unitdisk.

I already found that the period is approximate $T = \frac{1}{f} \leq  0.04$.

Now I wanted to find a exact solution. Using Matlab I have...

```
% define symbolic period
syms T;

% define A matrices
A{1} = [-0.5 1; 100 -1];
A{2} = [-1 -100; -0.5 -1];
Aeig = eig(expm(T/2*A{2})*expm(T/2*A{1}))

% solve
solve(abs(Aeig(1)) <= 1,abs(Aeig(2)) <= 1,T)
```

Unfortunatly Matlab gives

> Warning: 2 equations in 1 variables. 
>   In /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/toolbox/symbolic/symbolic/symengine.p>symengine
>   at 54   In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.evalin at 97   In
>   mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.feval at 150   In solve at 160
>   In S02E01 at 14  Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
>   in solve at 169   In S02E01 at 14

What goes wrong here? I guess the problem lies in the fact that Aeig has two pretty huge equations?

Answer (score 1):

Switched stability is an open problem in control theory. For a good discussion and some pointers, see problem 6.4, page 203, in Blondel, V., & Megretski, A. (2004). Unsolved problems in mathematical systems and control theory‎, 334.

So the problem must be that the code is asking Matlab to do more than it is capable of.....